# Django adding an empty label to Choice Field using a ValueListQuery Set for distinct values

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to use a ValueListQuerySet with a empty label in a form that filters the results shown on a page. I had success using [EmptyChoiceField code](https://gist.github.com/davidbgk/651080) (this code is also cut in paste in my code below), however when I try to move the choices into the the init, as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707991/django-modelchoicefield-using-distinct-values-from-one-model-attribute), so that the choices refresh every time the form loads I end up losing the empty value (see my comments in the code below).

```
class EmptyChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, choices=(), empty_label=None, required=True, widget=None, label=None, initial=None, help_text=None, *args, **kwargs):

        # prepend an empty label if it exists (and field is not required!)
        if not required and empty_label is not None:
            choices = tuple([(u'', empty_label)] + list(choices))
        super(EmptyChoiceField, self).__init__(choices=choices, required=required, widget=widget, label=label, initial=initial, help_text=help_text, *args, **kwargs) 


class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    # The next line has the empty label but the list won't get updated when the form loads
    x = EmptyChoiceField(choices=Stuff.objects.all().values_list("x", "x").distinct(), required=False, empty_label="Show All")
    # The values get updated in the next line, but the empty_label stops working
    y = EmptyChoiceField(choices=[], required=False, empty_label="Show All")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['y'].choices= Stuff.objects.all().values_list("y", "y").distinct()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` will call the `EmptyChoiceField.__init__` method, and you are then overriding the choices right after the super call so you are overridding the choices the `EmptyChoiceField` set.

There are a few ways to solve this, I am not sure which one is the best, but the easiest way is to do the following in the `FilterForm.__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    choices = Stuff.objects.all().values_list("y", "y").distinct()
    self.fields['y'].choices = tuple([(u'', empty_label)] + list(choices))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I had to add add `empty_label="Show All"` under the init, otherwise it was complaining that the global variable empty_label was not defined. Also you explanation was informative, thanks again.