# Form to show unique values from Model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Learning Django.. I am trying to setup the below and need your expert advise to make it better..

I created a model, and form on top of it to show the data.. and I have two questions after the code where I need your advise :)

**Model:**

```
class profilestable(models.Model):
   choices = [
   ('Active','Active'),
   ('Inactive','Inactive')
   ]
   Category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   SubCategory = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Status = models.ChoiceField(max_length=20,choices=choices)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.Category

class Userlist(models.Model):
       User = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       Categorygroup = models.ForeignKey(profilestable,null=true,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    
       def __str__(self):
          return self.User
```

**Form:**

```
class userprofileform(forms.ModelForm):
   model = Userlist
   Fields = ('User','CategoryGroup')

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
   super(userprofileform,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

**Sample data in the profilestable Model:**

[image]

Queries:

1. I want to add the category, subcategory and product name as drop downs to the form however I am not sure how to access each element to show on the form. I was able to pull only category since I am returning that value.
2. The list currently has lots of duplicate values, is it possible to show only unique values in the drop down.
3. Also, is it possible to make it a multi-select and dependent cascading drop downs

Request you to please help advise/direct to implement this type of form.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The structure needs some changes, for example `category` should be a parent of `sub-category`, and then `product` lives below `sub-category`, so it would be better to create a separates models for `Category`, `Sub-category` and `Product` in this relation:

`Category > Sub-category > Product` Since sub-category and products are not unique relation to its parent, use the `ForeignKey` Field to connect them.

Also I see in your `sample data` and many products are shinked in 1 row, that is not good in any terms of scaling, performance or order.

Yet I cannot see the usecase of your `Userlist` model.

Once done the above please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6708285/12581324) to create your drop down menu, althought the distinct at the end is not needed as creating separate model for `Category` will avoid the need to duplicate `Category` names. Then on form submition, you Query for the correct `Category` and `Sub-Category` instance and assign it to the `ForeignKey` field of your form.

Comment: The challenge is.. the data is just a raw excel report that is sent on a monthly basis that will loaded to a table for reference to use as a drop down. since it changes every month and it would be hard to split the table into three models.. I was hoping to keep it same and implement it. any thoughts?

Comment: And what is the problem with that tho ? You get the name of the category from the excel column, query for that category in the database and assign it to the ForeignKey. Not complex tho

Comment: @KarthikViz Well if you insist to leave it as all in one model, it will drop a lot performance, using the link I provided above, you can add the add distinct() at the end of you queries to return you only unique values